# Adding and subtracting a value within a table using either JavaScript or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

So I have a leaderboard set up at work which is put together using php, a lot of MySQL and some pretty looking CSS.
You can see in the table that I have a column labelled 'Flukes' - I'd like to add a tiny + and - button on either side of the value which will increase or decrease the value, and somehow I'd like to add this for each person. I've been trying to find some nice JavaScript to create this but I don't seem to know how to add this for each individual person

[League Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxHiV.png)

Below is a snippet from the code, the rest above is just all the MySQL needed to pull this information out.

```
    <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Score</th>
            <th>Game Count</th>
            <th>Flukes</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <? foreach($aPlayers as $aPlayer)
{
         if ($aPlayer['lGameCount'] > 0 && $aPlayer['lGameCount'] < 4)
        { ?>
            <tr class="yellow" style="text-align:center;">
                <td><?=$aPlayer['PlayerName']?></td>
                <td><?=round($aPlayer['lScore'])?></td>
                <td><?=$aPlayer['lGameCount']?></td>
                <td><?=$aPlayer['lFlukes']?></td>
            </tr>
<?  }
            elseif ($aPlayer['lGameCount'] > 3)
        { ?>
                <tr class="green" style="text-align:center;">
                    <td><?=$aPlayer['PlayerName']?></td>
                    <td><?=round($aPlayer['lScore'])?></td>
                    <td><?=$aPlayer['lGameCount']?></td>
                    <td><?=$aPlayer['lFlukes']?></td>
                </tr>
<?  }
            else
        { ?>
                <tr class="red" style="text-align:center;">
                    <td><?=$aPlayer['PlayerName']?></td>
                    <td><?=round($aPlayer['lScore'])?></td>
                    <td><?=$aPlayer['lGameCount']?></td>
                    <td><?=$aPlayer['lFlukes']?></td>
                </tr>
<?  }
} ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you need the +/- buttons to update the flukes value on the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a JQuery-based Solution you might want to try. We simulated an Array representing the Result of MySQL Data like so:

**PHP**

```
        <?php

            $aPlayers = [
                [
                    "pPlayerID"      => "1",
                    "PlayerName"    => "Johnny",
                    "lScore"        => "3113",
                    "lGameCount"    => "41",
                    "lFlukes"       => "42",
                ],
                [
                    "pPlayerID"      => "2",
                    "PlayerName"    => "Phil",
                    "lScore"        => "3022",
                    "lGameCount"    => "13",
                    "lFlukes"       => "40",
                ],
                [
                    "pPlayerID"      => "3",
                    "PlayerName"    => "Jammizle",
                    "lScore"        => "2994",
                    "lGameCount"    => "62",
                    "lFlukes"       => "100",
                ],
                [
                    "pPlayerID"      => "4",
                    "PlayerName"    => "Gary",
                    "lScore"        => "2989",
                    "lGameCount"    => "10",
                    "lFlukes"       => "0",
                ],
                [
                    "pPlayerID"      => "4",
                    "PlayerName"    => "Johnathan",
                    "lScore"        => "2985",
                    "lGameCount"    => "9",
                    "lFlukes"       => "5",
                ],
                [
                    "pPlayerID"      => "5",
                    "PlayerName"    => "Kevin",
                    "lScore"        => "2970",
                    "lGameCount"    => "17",
                    "lFlukes"       => "5",
                ],
                [
                    "pPlayerID"      => "6",
                    "PlayerName"    => "Jason",
                    "lScore"        => "2882",
                    "lGameCount"    => "11",
                    "lFlukes"       => "62",
                ],
                [
                    "pPlayerID"      => "7",
                    "PlayerName"    => "Stewart",
                    "lScore"        => "2882",
                    "lGameCount"    => "81",
                    "lFlukes"       => "56",
                ],
                [
                    "pPlayerID"      => "8",
                    "PlayerName"    => "Chris",
                    "lScore"        => "3015",
                    "lGameCount"    => "1",
                    "lFlukes"       => "75",
                ],
                [
                    "pPlayerID"      => "9",
                    "PlayerName"    => "Nick",
                    "lScore"        => "2985",
                    "lGameCount"    => "1",
                    "lFlukes"       => "98",
                ],
            ];
        ?>
```

We then changed the Structure of your Table to have classes so that we can work with the classes in JQuery and we also added a little CSS to help us visualize the Process like so:

**HTML**

```
        <style type="text/css">
            .increase-flukes,
            .decrease-flukes{
                cursor:pointer;     /* <== ADD A POINTER CURSOR TO INDICATE YOU CAN CLICK TO INCREASE OR DECREASE FLUKES*/
                font-weight:bold;
                font-size: 18px;
                display:inline-block;
                min-width:20px;
                text-align: center;
                color:red;
            }
            td.flukes-cell{
                text-align: left;
            }
        </style>




        <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Score</th>
                <th>Game Count</th>
                <th>Flukes</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <? foreach($aPlayers as $aPlayer)
            {
                if ($aPlayer['lGameCount'] > 0 && $aPlayer['lGameCount'] < 4)
                { ?>
                    <tr class="yellow" style="text-align:center;">
                        <td><?php echo $aPlayer['PlayerName'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo round($aPlayer['lScore']);?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $aPlayer['lGameCount'];?></td>
                        <td class="flukes-cell">
                            <span class="increase-flukes" data-pid="<?php echo $aPlayer['pPlayerID'];?>">+</span>
                            <span class="flukes" id="fluke-<?php echo $aPlayer['pPlayerID'];?> " data-pid="<?php echo $aPlayer['pPlayerID'];?>"><?php echo $aPlayer['lFlukes'];?></span>
                            <span class="decrease-flukes" data-pid="<?php echo $aPlayer['pPlayerID'];?>">-</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?  }
                elseif ($aPlayer['lGameCount'] > 3)
                { ?>
                    <tr class="green" style="text-align:center;">
                        <td><?php echo $aPlayer['PlayerName'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo round($aPlayer['lScore']);?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $aPlayer['lGameCount'];?></td>
                        <td class="flukes-cell">
                            <span class="increase-flukes" data-pid="<?php echo $aPlayer['pPlayerID'];?>">+</span>
                            <span class="flukes" id="fluke-<?php echo $aPlayer['pPlayerID'];?> " data-pid="<?php echo $aPlayer['pPlayerID'];?>"><?php echo $aPlayer['lFlukes'];?></span>
                            <span class="decrease-flukes" data-pid="<?php echo $aPlayer['pPlayerID'];?>">-</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?  }
                else
                { ?>
                    <tr class="red" style="text-align:center;">
                        <td><?php echo $aPlayer['PlayerName'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo round($aPlayer['lScore']);?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $aPlayer['lGameCount'];?></td>
                        <td class="flukes-cell">
                            <span class="increase-flukes" data-pid="<?php echo $aPlayer['pPlayerID'];?>">+</span>
                            <span class="flukes" id="fluke-<?php echo $aPlayer['pPlayerID'];?> " data-pid="<?php echo $aPlayer['pPlayerID'];?>"><?php echo $aPlayer['lFlukes'];?></span>
                            <span class="decrease-flukes" data-pid="<?php echo $aPlayer['pPlayerID'];?>">-</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?  }
            } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Finally, we married the HTML with JQuery  like so:

**JAVASCRIPT: JQUERY**

```
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            ;                           // CLOSE OFF ANY UNCLOSED JS TAGS... IF ANY ;-)
            jQuery.noConflict();        // ADD THE noConflict() METHOD, IN CASE YOU ARE USING OTHER LIBRARIES THAT MAKE USE OF THE $ SYMBOL
            (function ($) {
                $(document).ready(function(e) {
                    // CREATE VARIABLES TO USE IN THE PROGRAM
                    var flukesCell  = $("td.flukes-cell");
                    flukesCell.each(function(data){
                        var decreaseFluke   = $(this).find(".decrease-flukes");
                        var increaseFluke   = $(this).find(".increase-flukes");
                        var flukeContent    = $(this).find(".flukes");

                        decreaseFluke.on("click", function(evt){
                            var flcVal  = flukeContent.text();
                            var id      = $(this).attr("data-pid");
                            if(flcVal != 0){
                                flcVal--;
                                flukeContent.text(flcVal);
                                performAjaxSave(flcVal, id);
                            }
                        });

                        increaseFluke.on("click", function(evt){
                            var flcVal  = flukeContent.text();
                            var id      = $(this).attr("data-pid");
                            flcVal++;
                            flukeContent.text(flcVal);
                            performAjaxSave(flcVal, id);
                        });
                    });

                    function performAjaxSave(flcVal, id){
                        var objData = {"id":id, "fluke":flcVal};
                        $.ajax({
                            url         : "ajax-processor.php",      //<== THIS SHOULD POINT TO THE PHP FILE THAT PROCESSES THE AJAX REQUEST. IF "ajax-processor.php" DOESN'T WORK FOR YOU, TRY: "./ajax-processor.php" OR USE THE FULL-URL
                            dataType    : "json",
                            cache       : false,
                            type        : "POST",
                            data        : (objData),

                            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                                if(data){
                                    alert(data.message);        // THIS COULD BE VERY ANNOYING, REALLY... BUT COULD BE HANDY DURING DEVELOPMENT... DELETE IT!!!
                                    console.log(data.message);
                                }
                            },

                            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                console.log('The following error occurred: ' + textStatus, errorThrown);
                            },

                            complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            })(jQuery);

        </script>
```

And now to save the Fluke back to the Database, Create a PHP-File in the same Directory as the Main File (probably your index.php file). In this case, we called it **ajax-processor.php** but you can as well call it anything but if you change the name, please make sure this new name is reflected in AJAX Section of your Javascript. Here are the Contents of the ajax-processor.php File:

```
    <?php
        // FILENAME: ajax-processor.php

        //DATABASE CONNECTION CONFIGURATION:
        defined("HOST")     or define("HOST", "localhost");           //REPLACE WITH YOUR DB-HOST
        defined("DBASE")    or define("DBASE", "sim");                //REPLACE WITH YOUR DB NAME
        defined("USER")     or define("USER", "root");                //REPLACE WITH YOUR DB-USER
        defined("PASS")     or define("PASS", "root");                //REPLACE WITH YOUR DB-PASS

        // GET THE POSTED VALUES OF THE FLUKE AND THE PLAYER ID FROM THE AJAX REQUEST...
        $playerID   = isset($_POST['id'])       ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['id']))      : null;
        $fluke      = isset($_POST['fluke'])    ? htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['fluke']))   : null;

        $response   = ['message'=>'Error updating Fluke for the Player with ID: ' . $playerID];

        try {
            $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=' . HOST . ';dbname=' . DBASE, USER, PASS);
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            // NOW UPDATE THE FLUKES ONLY IN THE tPlayers TABLE USING THE DATA ABOVE
            $sql    = "UPDATE tPlayers SET rFlukes=:RFL WHERE pPlayerID=:PID";
            $stmt   = $dbh->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':RFL', $fluke);
            $stmt->bindParam(':PID', $playerID);
            $status = $stmt->execute();

            if($status){
                $response["message"]    = "Update was Successful!!";
            }

            //GARBAGE COLLECTION
            $dbh = NULL;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $response["message"]    = $e->getMessage();
        }

        die(json_encode($response));
```

And the Result is that you can now click the Plus and minus Signs to increase or decrease the value of the Flukes plus save the value to the Database with each click of the Plus or Minus Buttons, respectively. However, feel Free to change the Plus & Minus Signs using perhaps classes from Bootstrap or Font-Awesome. It is hoped that this would help get you started, my Friend. Good-Luck ;-)

Comment: This looks great! The values decrease and increase on request! But one thing, is there a way of saving this back to the database? Thats where I'm stuck

Comment: @Jamie Belcher   You can do that using AJAX. I mean you can save the data back to the Database using AJAX and that should be easy to implement in the current Javascript that you have.

Comment: I'll take your word for it and mark this as the answer, thank you!

Comment: @JamieBelcher Thanks for the Up-Vote, though. I can help you with the AJAX Part too because it is quite easy though. But, then we'd have to work together. This means: You may need to show me the structure of the Table so that I can see how to craft the Processing PHP Script because we need the ID of the Players like Johnny, Phil, etc. to be able to make it work. Could you just upload an Image of your Table here? Just the Table Definition, i mean...?

Comment: Hey it's an open source project, originally made to give people a league table for any 2 player game, would you like the link? You could view everything there?

Comment: @JamieBelcher   If it does not violate any privacy, and you think it is wise to post it here, then OK

Comment: Well it was all created here within my office, so no violation there, I'll shove the link https://github.com/PinnaclePSM/leaguetable

Comment: @JamieBelcher  Perfect, Got it.... give me a few minutes to go through the Docs & stuff and i will update the Post to reflect the new changes that you wanted ;-)

Comment: @JamieBelcher Check out the new Changes and let us know if saving to the Database via AJAX worked as well....

Comment: Doesn't seem to be saving to the database still

Comment: @JamieBelcher Sorry I saw it now... a Typo in the Ajax Section of the Javascript.... ***i wrote data-id instead of data-pid...*** Now, Corrected.... ;-)

Comment: I've corrected the type, but again it's refusing to save to database

Comment: @JamieBelcher Down here it works for me.... *Did you change the SQL on the game.php File: on Line 90?* Look at the new Structure of your Data (above in the 1st PHP Section) it should have a PlayerID... and also note that the Table has some new Additions so you should take everything into consideration...  ***At the bottom of the above post is a section: IMPORTANT. Look into that too...***

Comment: screen for screen identical, not sure what it is

Comment: @JamieBelcher Yeee.... We have the PlayerID twice... OK... no need to change anything in game.php.... ***Just copy the updated Table in the HTML Section*** and it should work just fine...

Comment: IT WORKS, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to update your database then change the flukes column structure from

```
<td><?=$aPlayer['lFlukes']?></td>
```

to

```
<td><a onclick="decrease(this)">-</a><span class="value"><?=$aPlayer['lFlukes']?></span><a onclick="increase(this)">+</a></td>
```

and add the following javascript functions to your source

```
function increase(elem) {
  var valueElem = elem.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("value")[0];
  valueElem.textContent = (valueElem.textContent*1+1);
}

function decrease(elem) {
  var valueElem = elem.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("value")[0];
  valueElem.textContent = (valueElem.textContent*1-1);
}
```